# How to mix vertical and horizontal form elements in one form in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-form-helper

I am trying to create a form that mixes horizontal and vertical elements. I have managed to do it and it looks nice: http://www.bootply.com/rOibTngOct (you can see the result on bootply but I'll put the code here also)

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-9 control-label">Choice that you prefer</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control select">
          <option>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-5 control-label">Another choice</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <select class="form-control select">
          <option>very long choice C</option>
          <option>very long choice D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But as you can see I am resorting to 3 different forms! I need to have only one form (to submit it through AJAX to the server)

I need help! I tried this: http://www.bootply.com/pCCodAQaKN

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-9 control-label">Choice that you prefer</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control select">
          <option>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-5 control-label">Another choice</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <select class="form-control select">
          <option>very long choice C</option>
          <option>very long choice D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And it looks awfull. So my questions are:

- Is there a way to do this with standard bootstrap 3?
- If not how to do it with custom classes? (I honestly tried 2 different solutions but with no avail)
- Or, is it possible to send through AJAX several forms at the same time?

Comment: Give your controls' IDs, then add the values to the AJAX call, rather than trying to use forms.

Comment: Would love to know Why I was downvoted! This question has a clear answer (look at Henri's),I put all the source code needed, and I did a lot of research before posting it here!

Comment: People are quick to down vote.

Comment: Looks like this is a potential duplicate though it's unclear which version of Bootstrap was in the previous question. I went ahead an answered that one for Bootstrap 3 putting the sample code in the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596253/normal-vertical-form-inside-form-horizontal-with-twitter-bootstrap/34582089#34582089

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to use `form-horizontal` -class on a `<form>` element. Instead use a `<div>` and wrap all of the fields inside one `<form>` like this: http://www.bootply.com/hxs0IhA1wV

Comment: Since you were so fast I can only accept your answer in 5 minutes! Thank you!